# Kafka zookeeper-server-start: Error opening log file

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

Hello I am following this guide: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

I have run these commands:
[image]

I am getting this error message:

```
[0.002s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/g/kafka_2.13-3.2.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log': No such file or directory
[0.002s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/g/kafka_2.13-3.2.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log' using options 'filecount=10,filesize=100M' failed.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*:file=/g/kafka_2.13-3.2.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have Java 17 installed locally:
[image]

EDIT:

I just tried this on another pc, with a fresh java 18 installed, with JAVA_HOME environment variable se. Exact same issue..............

Comment: Please use WSL2, not Git Bash / MinGW. Also use Java 11 rather than 17 or higher

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ok so thats the problem, I need to run this in a linux vm?

Comment: WSL2 is a hypervisor, not a VM, but yes. You can also try the windows/bat files instead in command prompt/powershell, but people report limited success with those

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ok thanks for that, if I could mark this as an answer I would